# Ruby app thinks client's IP address is always the same

Tags: heroku, ip, sinatra

Sinatra app.

```
<%= request.ip %>
```

gives **127.0.0.1** IP address if looked at from local server.
gives **83.245.226.68** IP address if looked at from Heroku server, no matter from which device.
So I guess it returns server's IP address and not client's. How do I find out what client's IP address is then? Did I misunderstand *request.ip* method?

Comment: It should show 127.0.0.1 if you run it and view it on your dev machine. "if looked at from Heroku server, no matter from which device" - I'm guessing you mean _when it's deployed on a Heroku server, no matter which **local** device we use_? Are you caching the pages?

Comment: @iain, yes, that's what I meant. no, I don't cache them. It has to give  the user the IP of their device and not the IP of Heroku server, right?

Comment: http://agile-badlands-4146.herokuapp.com/ ------ ip shown to me is 83.245.226.68 and apparently everyone sees it as such.

Comment: Put `warn "!!!request.ip = #{request.ip}"` into the route, and check the logs. It should match up with the rest of the record Heroku is showing you. If you're all using the same WAN address that would explain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when the HTTP Server in front of the Rack HTTP Server (e.g. used for load balancing, ssl, etc) is not forwarding the client IP address to the Rack HTTP Server. In that case you get the IP address of the HTTP Server.

This can be configured on HTTP Servers like Nginx and Apache and you get the client IP address in `request.ip`.

As far as I know Heroku is doing it in a way that the client IP address is in a header called "x-forwarded-for", which is a comma separated list of IP addresses, the last element is the client ip.

Sinatra:

```
env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].split(',').last
```

Rails:

```
request.headers['x-forwarded-for'].split(',').last
```

Comment: Where can I enable the x-forwarded-for proxy setting on the nginx controller? Or how would I do it in GCP where I've installed nginx via the default github repository?